# can I log urls visited with dd-wrt?

Tags: wireless-networking, security, dd-wrt

Got dd-wrt setup!

Can I log urls visited on all computers on the network?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can actually use the following firewall rules on the dd-wrt firmware to force users to use a specified DNS server (in the router settings)

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p udp -i br0 --dport 53 -j DNAT --to $(nvram get lan_ipaddr)
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -i br0 --dport 53 -j DNAT --to $(nvram get lan_ipaddr)
```

This was supposed to be a comment to the answer posted by jason404 but I can't because of my low rep :)

Answer (score 2):

This feature is not currently available in the DD-WRT firmware.